# Change SubTab name in Service Console

Tags: tab, service-cloud-console, subtab-apps

I added a custom button to Contacts that when clicked in the Service Console opens a VF page in a subtab. However, the tab name is currently blank. How can I add/change the name of this SubTab?

This is the code opening the tab.

```
srcUp("https://na1.salesforce.com/apex/service_cloud_console_flow_1");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with this:

Service console integration toolkit has a method named `setTabTitle`

Ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(function(result) {
               // Result.id is the id of tab
               sforce.console.setTabTitle('Change Title', result.id);
        });
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/index.htm

Comment: What if I want to change the title of a standard page--like a Case?  I want to add some text to the case title--like 2015-00008752.  Is there a place to sneak-in some Javascript without going all VF?

Answer (score 1):

I had exact issue and able to fixed, here is the how I did it:

[source](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205552&language=en_US#attachments)

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/20.0/integration.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testSetTabTitle() {
            //Set the current tab's title
            sforce.console.setTabTitle('Lead: {!Lead.Name}');
        }
        var pageLoad = window.onload;
          window.onload = function() {
                if (pageLoad) {
                        pageLoad();
                }
                  testSetTabTitle();
          }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is possible with this internal SFDC function. As mentioned in this topic ([The Service Cloud Console – Working with Buttons and Links](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YKxYAAW)):

> when opening Salesforce.com pages, the tab title is set automatically.

and

> when opening Visualforce pages, the Visualforce page is responsible
>   for setting its tab title.

But... Why not using a native [service cloud console integration API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/index.htm)? It is working well for me:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/30.0/integration.js")}

// Use the results primary tab id and open a new subtab
var openSubtab = function(result){            
    sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, 'your page url', true, 'page title', null);    
};
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
```

Answer (score -3):

I achieved[image] this using Aura Component and Controller.

Below image shows case subject instead of case number.

Comment: As with [your other answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/413996/24889), this isn't a helpful answer. You need to share your code _and explain how it works_.